# Rails as_josn nested multiple assocoations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nested, associations

```
user.as_json(
  include: [
    user_purchased_packages: {
      include: [
        business_package: {
          include: [
            business: {
              include: :business_address
            },
            package: {
              include: :services
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
)
```

as I passed in the array

```
[:business=>{:include=>:business_address},:package=>{:include=>:services}]
```

So it is expecting that the business and package both objects values should come.

but I am only able to get the business object and package object is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

user.as_json(include: { :user_bookings=>{include: [:business_category_service_sub_services,:business => {include: :business_address}], methods: [:date_format]}, :user_purchased_packages=>{:include=>[:business_package=>{:include=>{:package => {include: :services} , :business=>{include: :business_address} } }  ] , methods: [:date_format] }  }, methods: [:followers_count,:following_count,:full_name])